# How to calculate how much variance a set of regressors explains on another data set using PCA transformation?

Tags: regression, variance, pca

I am running a PCA on a dataset and I obtain a set of regressors. Now I would like to decompose **another dataset** onto the same basis of regressors and to know how much variance of the second dataset each of my regressors explains ?

Comment: What do you call `regressors` in that context?

Comment: I call regressors the eigenvectors identified by the pca

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps

- Get the transformation/rotation from your PCA
- Apply the transformation to the second data set
- Calculate the variance from transformed data, by column

Here is the code on a toy data set.

```
set.seed(0)
d1=scale(USArrests)
d2=scale(USArrests+matrix(runif(nrow(USArrests)*ncol(USArrests)),
                          ncol=ncol(USArrests))*10)

pr.out=prcomp(d1, scale=F)
pr.var=apply(pr.out$x,2,sd)^2
pve=pr.var/sum(pr.var)
plot(cumsum(pve), xlab="Principal Component",
     ylab="Cumulative Proportion of Variance Explained",
     ylim=c(0.5,1),type='b', lwd=2)
grid()

x2=as.matrix(d2) %*% pr.out$rotation
pr.var2=apply(x2,2,sd)^2
pve2=pr.var2/sum(pr.var2)
lines(cumsum(pve2),type='b',col=2,lwd=2)
legend(2, 0.7, c("Variance Explained in Data 1",
                   "Variance Explained in Data 2"), lwd=c(2,2), col=c(1,2))
```

The output plot is:

[image]

Note, the original data has 4 features, and if we do not reduce the dimension, and use all of them. We can always explain $100%$ of the variance in any data set. This is why you see, two curves meet at the top right corner.

Comment: Great, thank you very much for your help.
Actually I am using matlab, so I guess it should be something like that right ?  

`% svd decomposition `  
`[u,s,v]=svd(data1);`  
  
`% rotation of the second dataset`  
`data2rot=inv(u)*data2*inv(v');`  
  
`% calculation of the variance`  
`var(data2rot)/sum(var(data2rot))`

Comment: I do not have the matlab code in my mind right now :). You can check the numbers by comparing 2 systems. BUT, one advice: never use `inv` function, because it is not numerical stable.

Comment: More about `inv`: suppose you want to solve a linear system $Ax=b$, do NOT use `inv(A)*b`, but use `linsolve`.

Comment: Thank you.
Actually it seems to give me reasonable results on two dataset but wrong results if I re-apply it on the same dataset (the data2rot matrix being diagonal, the var calculation gives wrong results)

Comment: In fact I think I will try to learn how to import my data in r and use your code. Thank you so much

Comment: @Alex no upvote no acceptance :)?